# Concatenate lookup fields in a calculated filed in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, concatenation, calculated-field

I have a table in a Microsoft Access 2013 database and I want to create a new calculated field that concatenates three lookup fields from this table.

I inserted a new field, defined it as "Calculated" and, using the expression builder, put in the following code:

```
[Field1] & " " & [Field2] & " " & [Field3]
```

What I got were numbers, like these:

```
23423 23 47
```

How can I get the values instead of the numbers?

Comment: Can you show us the expected result?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes As an English language learner, I've created my own dictionary of phrasal verbs in MS Access. The first field takes verbs from a list of English words (there're hundreds of thousands of them). The list is stored in a separate table. There're also two fields for particles and they take values from a separate list for particles. So, as a result, I expect something like this:`come away with`

Answer (score 0):

See [Create or delete a lookup field](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-delete-a-lookup-field-87e84cbd-d60c-4473-8a98-3e391c42f239) to create a lookup field in a table. I don't know if you can lookup values in a calculated field in a table. You could try to use the `DLookUp` function, but event if it works, the performance will be bad. You are better off with creating a query for this purpose.

Something like this

```
SELECT d.Description, w1.Description & ' ' & w2.Description & ' ' & w3.Description  AS sentence
FROM
    ((dictionary d
    LEFT JOIN words w1 ON d.Id = w1.Id)
    LEFT JOIN words w2 ON d.Id = w2.Id)
    LEFT JOIN words w3 ON d.Id = w3.Id
```

But it is very difficult to give you a more detailed answer with the very few pieces of information you gave us.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the lookup hides the number that is actually stored in the table.  to fix the query, add the look ups manually to your query.
the field with a look up is usually a foreign key to another table.  the idea behind a lookup is to show a more intuitive description just like you would with a combobox but the number is still there in the table.  the number is just visually wrapped in a combobox:
[image]

Hence the query:
[image]
gives the result:
[image]
To fix this just include the lookup in the query:
[image]
which gives the desired result:
[image]